# Return generic xts variable with R package quantmod getSymbol function

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am using the quantmod R package.
Is there a way to have getSymbols return a generic xts object instead of the symbol I am getting. For instance, if I have execute:

```
getSymbols("COKE", src='yahoo', index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"), from='1990-01-01')
```

It creates the xts object in the name of symbol COKE. As said, is there a way to return a xts data object to a generic variable like x. I.e.

```
x <- getSymbol(...)
```

I am have looked high and low for a solution but no answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in `?getSymbols` (emphasis added):

> Value:
>
> A call to getSymbols will load into the specified environment one
>     object for each ‘Symbol’ specified, with class defined by
>     ‘return.class’. Presently this may be ‘ts’, ‘its’, ‘zoo’, ‘xts’,
>     or ‘timeSeries’.
>
> **If ‘auto.assign’ is set to FALSE an object of type ‘return.class’
>     will be returned.**

For example:

```
x <- getSymbols("COKE", auto.assign=FALSE)
```

Before looking high and low, it's a good idea to read and understand the documentation. ;-)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for much Joshua! That was fast and a big time saver as well!

Comment: @heavyrockerdude: \m/ ^_^ \m/

Answer (score 0):

If getSymbols() didn't already offer the auto.assign parameter, the other way to do it is like this:

```
ret <- getSymbols("COKE", src='yahoo', index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"), from='1990-01-01')
x <- get(ret)
```

And if you didn't want COKE polluting your environment, look into green energy. ...sorry, bad joke. What you can do, to clean up, is this:

```
rm(list=ret);rm(ret)
```

(But this is just by the by, Joshua's answer is of course the correct one.)